# TFS Security: access to Reporting Services and Sharepoint for TFS Groups possible?

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services

There is a "How To" on adding developers to the TFS on MSDN.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668968.aspx

It has 3 main parts:
Step 1 – Grant Access to the Team Project
Step 2 – Grant Access to the SharePoint Project Site
Step 3 – Grant Access to SQL Server Reporting Services

Fair enough, it works for individual developers.

Now, what if I manage my developers by creating groups on project/server level in TFS, i.e. in my Project1 I add developers to the [Project1]\Contributors TFS Group.

Is there a way to grant access to Sharepoint and Reporting Services for this [Project1]\Contributors group or will I be limited to adding Windows users/groups?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If anyone is interested, I found a tool called TFS Admin Tool

http://www.codeplex.com/TFSAdmin
It's buggy and unstable, and does not do exactly what I need, but very close to.

"The TFS Admin Tool allows a TFS administrator to quickly add users to all three platforms utilized by Team Foundation Server: Team Foundation Server, Sharepoint, and SQL Reporting Services, all through one common interface. The tool also allows administrators to change the current permissions on any of the three tiers, identify any errors, and view all of the users and their permission sets across Team Foundation Server, Sharepoint, and SQL Reporting Services."

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint will allow you to create a group within SharePoint only. You can then permission that group just as you would expect if it were an AD (windows) group.